# iframe cutting off at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a page with an iframe that displays an image and comments. I don't want anyone to be required to click in the iframe and scroll to see all the content. I've set the height of the iframe to 2500px in hopes that I would only have to scroll the parent frame to view all the content. This isn't working though, it just cuts off at the bottom of the window, forcing me to click inside the iframe and scroll to view everything.

in short, I want to view all content within iframe, without having to click inside the iframe to scroll inside it. any way to do this with css or js?

Comment: Can you replicate this using jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you have to use an iframe? Can't you just load the content in a div?

Comment: @ctwheels for some reason I can't seem to replicate the problem. here is a link though www.makeartforme.com/gallery?i=14

Comment: @gillesc I could change some things around with my php to not have to rely on an iframe. If I can't fix this problem I'll go through that process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the iframe on the same domain?

It is not a good idea to give a pixel size to a variable size iframe.

This is a solution for a dynamic size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(iframe) {
      iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
</script>
```

and on  you iframe in the html:

```
<iframe onload="resizeIframe(this)" ...
```

Comment: thank you! the iframe is on the same domain. this helped my layout look cleaner